# filter NSFetchedResultsController result swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I want automatic updates on tableview..For that i have used `NSFetchedResultsController`as

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    // Initialize Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Student")

    // Add Sort Descriptors
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "grade", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    // Configure Fetched Results Controller
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

But i have to filter the results after loading as of user selection as..

```
  @IBAction func onSegmentValueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl)
    {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{

            //filter by grade
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Student")
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "grade", ascending: true)
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
            let filterfetchResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "address = %@","Russia")
            filterfetchResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }else{

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Student")
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "grade", ascending: true)
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
            let filterfetchResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "grade = %d",10)
            filterfetchResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
            self.tableView.reloadData()


        }

    }
```

This however reload the tableView but data is not filtered.how do i solve this problem?[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6dTvD1JbkgBbUtQb0tTLTZaZVE/view?usp=sharing) is the demo project i am working on.Or should i use the normal way passing the results and reloading tableView as of normal way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You must use `self.fetchedResultsController`, this is your datasource, not `filterfetchResultsController`: there´s no connection.
2. You must do a performFetch() to execute the changed predicates

This works for me:

```
@IBAction func onSegmentValueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl)
{
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{

        //filter by address
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "address == %@","Russia")
        self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    }else{

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "grade = %d",10)
        self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    }

    do {
        try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.userInfo)")
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: is this the best way to address my problem?

Comment: _i_ think, that in your code the self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch() is missing and you dont use the right fetchedResultsController. In my app this way works. But is it the **best** way? I would never contend for this, you can ever learn new ways. ;-)